# When click the image button, open new view in Swift UI

Tags: swiftui

I would like to open new View after clicking on a image button in SwiftUI, any idea?

```
Button(action: {}) {
    Image("gift")
    Text("Send")
        .padding(.horizontal)
}
.padding()
.foregroundColor(.white)
.background(Color.gray)
.cornerRadius(.infinity)
```

Comment: it is so simple what is your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it in a `NavigationView`, you can use a `NavigationLink` instead of a `Button`:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Image("gift")
                    Text("Send")
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .cornerRadius(.infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail")
    }
}
```

If you want a `sheet` presented, you can use the `sheet` modifier and a `@State` variable:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var sheetPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            sheetPresented = true
        }) {
            Image("gift")
            Text("Send")
                .padding(.horizontal)
        }
        .padding()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .background(Color.gray)
        .cornerRadius(.infinity)
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheetPresented) {
            DetailView()
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail")
    }
}
```